# Concatenating functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working in a js-component and i was wondering if there's a better way to concatenate functions in javascript then returning `this`. I have a sample code working here, and that's how i solved the problem.

```
function hi(){
  console.log('hi');
  return this;
}
function bye(){
  console.log('bye');
  return this;
}
function Test(){};

Test.prototype.hi = hi;
Test.prototype.bye = bye;

var x = new Test();

x
 .hi() //hi
 .bye(); //bye
```

Comment: Was one of those prototypes meant to be adding `bye`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any other way, let alone a better one.

Comment: By concatenate, I think you mean chain?

Comment: Also, you need to quantify "better" if you want an objective answer. Otherwise, this question risks closure as "primarily opinion based". See [ask].

Comment: In order to make method chaining work, you have to return the object that implements the interface you want to chain. And that's `this`. Not really anything else you can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well known pattern called a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) - it can certainly help write code in certain circumstances, but like everything it has a purpose but shouldn't be used for everything.